# The internal architecture of apt management system?

Tags: linux, debian, aptitude

To make it more concrete, what's the relationship among apt-get, apt-file, apt-cache, aptitude and dpkg? I know that aptitude is the friendly front end to dpkg - so is apt-get, but less friendly. So is aptitude built upon apt-get? Is all of the apt*s the front-end of dpkg?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `dpkg` is the main workhorse and database keeper.
- `apt-get` is a commandline front-end and provides dependency checking.
- `aptitude` is commandline & ncurses front-end that provides a terminal GUI (as you say, friendlier than `apt-get`).

All the other `apt-*` are tools to do specific things:

- `apt-cache` performs searches on your system's local package cache (including what it knows about enabled repositories).
- `apt-file` is used for searching for particular files in the cache.  While `dpkg -S` can tell you what package an installed file came from, `apt-file` can tell you what files an uninstalled package will install.
- `apt-src` is a bit like apt-get for source packages.  doesn't require root.